# R filtering rows using dply when column value contains one of three values

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

Have a dataframe where a single column (Play) contains text (sample below)

I wish to filter the dataframe when the Play column contains one of these values "makes","misses","rebound"

Be nice to do in dplyr but will take anything since cannot find anything that works.

```
Play
Ben Simmons vs. Mark Williams (LaMelo Ball gains possession)
P.J. Washington misses two point driving floating jump shot
Spencer Dinwiddie defensive rebound
Ben Simmons makes two point running finger roll layup
Spencer Dinwiddie makes two point running layup (Ben Simmons assists)
```

Comment: Try `df[-grep("makes|missed|rebound", ignore.case = TRUE, df$Play),]` or in the dplyr/tidyverse,  `df %>% filter(!stringr::str_detect(tolower(Play), "makes|missed|rebound"))`

Comment: The dplyr line works perfectly.  I had tried something similar but had used c("makes","missed",rebound") and it must have choked on that.

Comment: @jpsmith, why the shift from `grep` to `str_detect`? I'd think `!grepl` would work just as well.

Comment: @r2evans I agree (that’s how I would do it) but wanted to keep the latter approach wholly within the tidyverse and no base R - great point though!